# How to add elements of the same index in two seqs together in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have

```
[1 1 1 1 1]
```

and

```
[2 2 2 2 2]
```

I want

```
[3 3 3 3 3]
```

I tried

```
(for [x s1
      y s2
      :when (= (.indexOf s1 x) (.indexOf s2 y))]
   (+ x y))
```

It gives wrong result because .indexOf doesn't return its acctual index but search it using its value.

Any one can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `map`:

```
(map + [1 1 1 1 1] [2 2 2 2 2])
;; => (3 3 3 3 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `core.matrix` ([link](https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api)), then operators can be extended to work with vectors of numbers and you can just do:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix.operators)

(+ [1 1 1 1 1] [2 2 2 2 2])
=> [3 3 3 3 3]
```

In general, you should be looking a `core.matrix` if you are going to do a lot of work with vectors / matrices / multi-dimensional arrays in Clojure.